# apt want to downgrade to older package version

Tags: apt, dpkg

In ubuntu 14.04 I have just compiled lm-sensors ver. 3.3.5 and install it using **dpkg -i**, after that when running **apt-get update**, apt want to downgrade it to older (repository) version. How to resolve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I' ve found this solution:

> **sudo apt-mark hold *packet***

It won't upgrade packet marked as hold